# Getting error when publishing iOS via nativescript tns command

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

When I try to publish using following command, it's giving me error. I searched around and didn't find anything on google.

Command:

```
tns publish ios <apple id> <password> --appleApplicationSpecificPassword <app specific pass> --ipa <ipa file path>
```

Error message that I'm getting from nativescript cli: 
Although response from Apple indicated activated Two-step Verification or Two-factor Authentication, NativeScript CLI don't know how to handle this response: [object Object]

Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try setting `team-id`?

Comment: Thanks Manoj, I just wanted to publish and read that team-id is required for build and optional for publish. I did try now to provide it and it still returned the same error. Here's my command: tns publish ios myemail@email.com mypassword --appleApplicationSpecificPassword "zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz" --team-id A00AA00AAA --ipa <ipa file path>  I'm using 10 char team id

Comment: when i'm trying to use apple-login, i'm getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this configuration:-

1.Set apple app store configuration in

**App_Resources -> iOS ->  build.xcconfig**

2.Create Release IPA File With Bundle

**cmd:-**

```
tns build ios --for-device --release --bundle --env.uglify --env.*
```

3.Create IPA With Distribution Provision

**cmd:-**

```
tns build ios --for-device --release --provision < provision-UUID > --bundle webpack --env.uglify--env.*
```

OR

4.Upload IPA Package and build on App Store With Bundle

**cmd:-**

```
tns appstore upload --bundle < AppleID > < AppleID-Specific-Password > < provision-distribution-UUID >  "iOS Distribution"
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that (did #1, and then #3, and then #4). Getting error "The server returned unexpected response: Unauthenticated". At < AppleID-Specific-Password > i tried both my apple id account password and app specific password.

Comment: Generate your apple id specific password. https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204397

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by 'app specific password' in my previous reply. I have tried with that as well, same error.

Comment: Can I have a sample of the ```build.xcconfig``` file ?

because the configuration is kinda tricky

Answer (score 0):

Finally had to resort to :

```
xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios --file "$IPA_PATH" --username "$APP_STORE_USERNAME" --password "$APP_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD"
```

Doing so uploaded my ipa file to app store connect.